# How do I show all rows in DF where there are duplicate values in one column in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes which I am trying to merge based on one column (`df['Number and postcode']`). However, that column has a number of duplicate values so the merge doesn't work (it gives this error: # Check for duplicates). The other issue is that `df1['Number and postcode']` might also have a number of duplicate values. How can I solve this, please?

This is the formula I am using:

```
merged = pd.merge(df, df1[{'TOTAL_FLOOR_AREA', 'Bedrooms'}],how = 'inner', on = df['Number and postcode'])
```

Answer (score 1):

To see which rows are duplicates in your dataframe, you can simply use the Pandas built-in function `duplicated()`.

```
df[df.duplicated(subset=['Number and postcode'], keep=False)]
```

Subsequently, you can drop all duplicates from both dataframes before merging using:

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset='Number and postcode', inplace=True)
df1.drop_duplicates(subset='Number and postcode', inplace=True)
```

Comment: To drop rows which contain duplicates in one column, would if just be df['Number and postcode'].drop_duplicates(inplace=True)?

Comment: Yes, you can use that as well. Although, I typically prefer passing the columns to the subset parameter.

Comment: Thanks.  So I did these two functions: 
df.drop_duplicates(subset = 'Number and postcode',keep = 'last', inplace=True)
df1.drop_duplicates(subset = 'Number and postcode',keep = 'last', inplace=True)

And then ran 
merged = pd.merge(df, df1[{'TOTAL_FLOOR_AREA', 'Bedrooms'}],how = 'inner', on = df['Number and postcode'])

I still get the same error as before

Comment: @KurranTailor you need to fix your merge statement to `merged = pd.merge(df, df1, on=‘Number and postcode’, how=‘inner’)`